# Why can't we take a limiting relative frequency over nested spheres in relativistic spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, probability, observers, cosmological-inflation

The Measure Problem of eternal inflation cosmology is to determine the correct probability measure over the theoretically infinitely many individuals (or civilizations or worlds) for self-locating belief.  Ultimately we want to know what credence we should we assign to being in  a world with property P, according to a given model, so that we can judge how much the observation of P or not-P confirms or disconfirms the model.

A seemingly natural answer is just to take a finite sphere in spacetime, estimate the portion of observers in it where P holds out of all individuals in the sphere, then repeatedly expand the sphere and take the frequency of individuals observing P in the limit as the sphere grows without bound.

But at least one discussion of this problem asserts that, "in relativistic spacetime, the proposal to assign probabilities by taking limiting relative frequencies in sequences of nested spheres doesn’t even make sense" (Arntzenius and Dorr 2017).  Why not?

[EDIT 3 Oct 2020 - Earlier in the paper they write, "in relativistic space-times there is no useful notion of a ‘four-dimensional sphere’—the closest analogues of spheres are regions bounded by hyperboloids, but these regions will in general contain infinite numbers of observers and hence be useless for the purpose of taking limits."

So they seem to be arguing that the procedure doesn't even make sense in Special Relativity or a flat Minkowski spacetime.]

Never mind all the other issues about the reference class problem, what counts as an observer, etc.  I just want to know why taking limiting relative frequencies in sequences of nested spheres doesn’t make sense in relativistic spacetime.

[EDIT - Assume a flat Minkowski spacetime to begin with. "Spheres" in the Minkowski metric aren't finite, so that won't work.  And spheres in one observer's coordinates won't be spheres for another.  But can't we at least define nested bounded sets that grow without bound?]

Update:  Detailed reference

Arntzenius, Frank, and Cian Dorr. 2017. “Self-Locating Priors and Cosmological Measures”. In *The Philosophy of Cosmology*, ed. by Khalil Chamcham et al., 396–428. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11864/

Comment: Could you include a more precise reference than “Arntzenius and Dorr 2016” (and preferably with a hyperlink)?

Comment: Added full details and link.  Does that help?

Comment: I don't currently have time to read the reference, but just going off of the text in the question, one possibility is that different observers would disagree about what the boundaries of a "sphere" are in the first place. Two observers in different situations (i.e. one is in a strong gravitational field, or the two are moving relative to each other) would claim that the other observer's "spheres" are actually distorted.

Comment: Thank you, @Edouard (@Cham); I had missed that bit and it does clarify their thinking.  More fully, they write that "in relativistic space-times there is no useful notion of a ‘four-dimensional sphere’—the closest analogues of spheres are regions bounded by hyperboloids, but these regions will in general contain infinite numbers of observers and hence be useless for the purpose of taking limits."  This suggests to me that they think the only solution worth considering is a sphere in the Minkowski metric, but I think that's too narrow.

Comment: It seems to me that, at least in a flat Minkwoski spacetime, we could just define a sequence of nested spheres around an event using the Euclidean metric for a particular observer, i.e., x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 < n, where x, y, z, t are the coordinates of events relative to some specified reference frame.  The regions defined this way won't be concentric spheres for every observer, but for every observer they will still be nested open sets that grow without bound and eventually include every event in the spacetime.  Is there anything wrong with that in the flat Minkowski case?

Comment: @Matt That's a perfectly well-defined prescription in Minkowski space, but there is no measure problem in that context to begin with. The measure problem is an issue in eternal inflation where spacetime behaves extremely differently.

Comment: Uh, by your reluctance to withdraw your edit or change the relevant tags, are you actually asking about a vacuum solution, lacking matter or energy, in an inflationary multiverse?  What would comprise the "populations" that Dorr and Artzenius are attempting to compare, in their struggle to resolve inflation's "measure problem"?  Rival groups of the purely-hypothetical gravitons, or some varied mixtures of them with the equally-hypothetical inflatons?

Comment: I mean, I know that the less-anthropomorphic localities in a multiverse might be empty, and might comprise most of them, but what about us?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the claim.  They say, **in relativistic spacetime**, taking a limiting relative frequencies in sequences of nested spheres doesn’t make sense.  They don't say this doesn't make sense in a populated spacetime that's relevant to the discussion.  So I wanted to know what's the **reason** this doesn't make sense.  Is there some reason that stems from special relativity on its own?  That's what their remark about hyperboloids seems to suggest.  And if not, then what exactly about the relevant context rules out this option?

Comment: @Edouard, I wasn't reluctant to do anything; I only now learned of your suggested edit.  It was rejected by other users, not me.  But for the reasons in my previous comment, I want my edit to stand.  The Q is about D&A's claim, not all of inflationary cosmo.  So let's **start** in SR.  Does that alone rule out the prescription?  If not, then what exactly does?

Comment: @probably_someone, I think you're right; I think that's what they were thinking, and it's disappointing because I don't think that's really relevant.  Spheres, parabaloids, whatever -- any bounded open sets of events will do, unless the resulting frequency depends on it, and that seems unlikely.  And if it does, that must be for reasons that go beyond mere relativity.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a question best addressed to the authors of the paper.

Comment: I did message Arntzenius, an old acquaintance, but haven't heard back.  Here I have tried to put the question as a general theoretical one rather than one about the authors' intentions.  Is there indeed any reason why we can't take a limiting relative frequency over nested spheres in relativistic spacetime?

Answer (score 1):

I think commentator @probably_someone has the right answer.  Nested *spheres* in relativistic spacetime don't make sense because a sphere in one reference frame is not a sphere in others.  A natural idea, which Dorr and Arntzenius hint at, is to take spheres in the invariant Minkowski metric (the spacetime interval), but these will generally be hyperboloids of infinite volume and therefore not helpful for taking finite frequencies.

However, I think D&A have made a dialectical error by resting too much on the notion of a sphere *per se*.  If we just want to take a limiting relative frequency, it won't matter whether we take it over a sequence of spheres, ellipsoids, or any other bounded regions, provided the choice of regions is not biased towards the actual distribution of properties.  Concentric spheres in one reference frame will still be nested bounded regions in every other reference frame.

The relevant question, then, is this:  Is there a legitimate worry that we will get different frequencies depending on which reference frame we use to define our spheres?  Such variance would require a peculiar distribution of properties that is biased towards certain reference frames, and to argue for that would require considerations beyond mere relativity.

So in sum, frame-independent *spheres* are not well defined in any relativistic spacetime, but relativity on its own does not rule out taking a limiting relative frequency over *bounded regions* of spacetime.  If there is any obstacle to such a procedure, it must come from further considerations:  either (i) a peculiar frame-biased distribution of properties, (ii) considerations of mass and curvature in General Relativity, or (iii) other aspects of Eternal Inflation.  I would love to know what exactly the main obstacle is, but that is another question.

Comment: At https://mathinsight.org/hyperboloid_one_sheet , please note that the hyperboloid "is already 'infinitely' tall", so that the region within it is partially, but not completely, bounded, whereas the space within a 2-sphere (the surface of a ball, in plain English) is completely bounded.  Spacetime, which has four dimensions, is not completely bounded, as Einstein did not require it to have a beginning or end in either the spatial sense or the temporal one.  Are you suggesting that Dorr & Artzenius should use a 3-sphere, or glome (visible thru Wikipedia), in their analysis?  (Maybe they did.)

Comment: At https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11515.pdf , there's a paper you might find of interest, as its writer, in discussing (on its p.10) the Penrose-Terrell "rotation" which prevents observation of the Lorentz contraction of spheres moving at relativistic speeds, expresses a belief that it should be called a "distortion" instead, whereas Probably Someone had apparently felt it to be more like a physical rotation.  As passage thru time is conventionally considered to be uni-directional in our locality, the "distortion" viewpoint seems more plausible to me (at the moment)....

Comment: At math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/penrose.html , there's a list of Lorentz contractions that includes a "hyperbolical" one consistent with Dorr & Artzenius' conclusion that "regions bounded by hyperboloids" are the "closest useful approximation" to a sphere, in relativistic spacetimes: Traveling in a circle as it would on a sphere (the surface of a ball), a star (or its center of gravity) would contribute to that sphere's distorsion upon any "boost" (acceleration) at the 2nd of the two points mentioned, whereas the hypperbolic surfaces would accommodate its continuation in time.

Comment: So, what I think that what both you and the writer of the Arxiv paper I've cited may be missing, re Probably Someone's assessment of the situation, is that a sphere is not spatially infinite, whereas a hyperboloid is:  Changes in the rate of the passage of clock time occur upon acceleration, but would distort the shape of the surface of the object concerned sufficiently that it would no longer be a sphere.  I may differ from Probably Someone by assuming that such a change would also transform whatever being might be carrying the clock.

Comment: @Edouard, the fact that the interior of a spacetime sphere - glome - has *finite* measure and will contain at most finitely many "observers", while the interior of a hyperboloid does not, is precisely why spheres are useful for taking limiting relative frequencies while hyperboloids are not.  We take a finite region of spacetime, count the observers with property P and those without, expand the region, repeat, and take the limit. With an infinite region like a hyperboloid, we can't get started.  That aside, I'm not sure what your point is. I'll take a look at your references.

Comment: Oh, I see - I wrote 'hyperboloids' in my answer when I meant paraboloids.  As I said in my comments, hyperboloids are unbounded, infinite in a natural measure, likely to contain infinitely many observers, and consequently no good for present purposes.

Comment: Ellipsoids!  I meant ellipsoids, not parabaloids.  Jeez.